# How do I get an Atheros AR8162 working?

Tags: atheros

I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10, my ethernet network card did not work, I tried to do the same procedure as did the version of ubuntu 4.12, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have a clue how to do it?

```
lo        Link encap:Loopback Local  
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:684 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:684 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:66739 (66.7 KB) TX bytes:66739 (66.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW e0:06:e6:d0:da:3d  
          inet end.: 192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::e206:e6ff:fed0:da3d/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          pacotes RX:2040 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 quadro:0
          Pacotes TX:2352 erros:0 descartados:0 excesso:0 portadora:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1149462 (1.1 MB) TX bytes:307333 (307.3 KB)
```

Comment: do compiling in sudo mode, if you got errors

Comment: My system does not recognize any ethernet connection.

Comment: Post the results of the command: `$ ifconfig`

Answer (score 10):

OK, managed to fix the problem. I downloaded and installed `compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar.bz2` from http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/ .

```
tar -xvf compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar
cd compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p
scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```

Note: This fix will NOT work with newer versions of `compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar.bz2.` Alx was removed from newer versions. Use the exact file described here.

Update 2012/09/05: working on Dell Inspiron 14z with same chipset using the tarball compat-wireless-2012-09-01-pc.tar.bz2

Comment: Network(wired n wireless) are basic  requirements of a OS. Engineering should do their best to ensure drivers are included in the OS. Otherwise, they should provide links in the webpage that point to media download. This is my feedback

Comment: This works for me on Lenovo G780, however after I restart the Ethernet does not work again and I need to do the modprobe alx again. Anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: you need to edit /etc/modules file, in order to load the module "alx" everytime you reboot. Just add the "alx" in a new line in that file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Ubuntu 12.10 with Inspiron 14z), just installing the linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic package solved the problem. Here's the magic command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
```

If you can't run `apt-get` on your machine (because of the lack of a network connection) you can download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal-updates/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.5.0-27-generic). This link is for the 3.5.0.27 kernel - the latest in quantal. You may need a different verion of the package to match whatever you're running (see the output of `uname -a`).

Answer (score 1):

Connect to internet.

Open dash by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> key

type in `gksudo jockey-gtk` and then press enter.

This will search for restricted driver and install them.

Comment: Tried, but couldn't find a suitable driver. It says "No proprietary drivers are in use on this system"

Answer (score 1):

The driver `compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar.bz2` works well with my Ubuntu 11.04 "Natty" installed on my Toshiba NB510-117 PPL72E.

Here are the results of `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Device 1090 (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, see if your system recognises the primary connection as eth1 instead of eth0. My laptop has only eth1, not eth0.

For this, open 'Network Connections' from the Unity Loader (press 'super' aka 'windows' key). Now, under 'wired tab', edit the connection you get.

Check 'connect automatically' and choose your IPv4 & IPv6 settings.

Unplug the cable. Plug cable again.

See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Current Quantal (12.10) users should not need to install backported drivers, as the 3.5.0 kernel now has built-in support for the **alx** driver.

For users on Precise (12.04 LTS), life became equally easy with the 12.04.2 point release on Feb 14th. That release introduced the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which will make your LTS release run atop the latest stable kernel (and X stack) from Quantal.

To enable the LTS Enablement Stack (it is default from 12.04.2 onward, but does *not* get activated automatically when you upgrade to 12.04.2 from 12.04 or 12.04.1), install the **linux-generic-lts-quantal** package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

If you also want the X stack from the Quantal release, additionally:

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with same wired connection hardware. And it is not working. Can you please tell me how make it work without enabling the backports-modules. Because once I have tried to install from backports-modules and it creats some problem for me. It will be a great help for me.