# Problem installing ethernet and wireless driver in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, ethernet

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 14R. My ethernet and wireless controllers are:

```
Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
Network Controller Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

After reading from other posts I have downloaded `compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar.bz2` from another machine. But while doing make I have the following error

```
/home/rahul/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p/config.mk:242: "WARNING: CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT will be deactivated or not working because kernel was compiled with CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=n. Tools using wext interface like iwconfig will not work. To activate it build your kernel e.g. with CONFIG_LIBIPW=m."  
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh .config config.mk > include/linux  /compat_autoconf.h  
make -C /home/rahul/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p modules  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rahul/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p'  
/home/rahul/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p/config.mk:242: "WARNING: CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT will be deactivated or not working because kernel was compiled with CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=n. Tools using wext interface like iwconfig will not work. To activate it build your kernel e.g. with CONFIG_LIBIPW=m."    
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/rahul/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p modules  
make: Entering an unknown directory  
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.0-17-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.  
make: Leaving an unknown directory  
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rahul/Desktop/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p'  
make: *** [.compat_autoconf_compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Before installing alien software, check for proprietary drivers. Go to **System Settings** and open **Software Sources**. Then go to the Additional Drivers tab and check if there is an additional driver you can use. Maybe you have as well to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since neither your wired, nor wirreless are working and therefore you don't have internet you may first [download keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx), and use it download the necessary packages. Then follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/215923/27968) to solve wireless problem.

Then try [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157604/27968) for the ethernet card.