# How do I get my network drivers working?

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, lenovo, atheros

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo G580 with Atheros AR8162 Ethernet and Broadcom BCM4313 Wireless Driver.

I try the this:

[How do I get an Atheros AR8162 working?](https://askubuntu.com/a/157604)

but it doesn't work.

When I type `make install` it comes:

```
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.2.0-29.generic-pae/modules.dep.temp for wirting: Permission denied make *** [unistall] Error 1
```

**Edit: 05.02.2012**

After I try it with `sudo` (thx to maggotbrain) cablebased network works. I update my system and install the Broadcom-STA-WLAN-Driver.
Restart and after my reboot cablebased network doesn't work anymore and I can see wlan's but I can't connect.

Comment: Those instructions should have you running the command `sudo make install` not just `make install`. Same for the `modprobe` command. It should be `sudo modprobe alx`

Comment: Cablebased Network works, but my wireless lan not. I installed the Broadcom-STA-WLAN-Driver. I can see wlan networks but i cant connect.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it. So you're halfway there. ;-) Could you please update your question so the focus is just on solving your wireless card issue?

Comment: @somebodyneedhelp Please use the same account (register) - that enables you to edit your own questions rather than suggest it only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the manual compile and install, install the package `linux-generic-lts-quantal`. This will activate the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which will upgrade the Linux kernel in your 12.04 LTS to the version in Quantal (12.10). That kernel (3.5.0) has built-in support for the drivers you need.

You will find the package linux-generic-lts-quantal in your package manager, or from a command shell do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

You will find some background info on this solution in my reponse [to this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/260866/134479).

Comment: Don't update your question because this solution will work for many "unsupported network card on LTS" questions, not only for the card you're struggling with.