# Cannot set up LAN internet connection

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, lan

I just installed both current versions 12.04 and 12.10 of Ubuntu (not simultaneously) and i could not set up an internet connection. The ethernet port on my computer doens't light up when i'm in Ubuntu as it does when i'm on Windows. Furthermore, there is no AutoEth0 option, and when i try to do things manually, it prevents me from being able to save the set up.

And for the life of me i can't find the console where one types the ifconfig command which displays all the info about networking.

The fact that the ethernet port on my pc doesn't light up leads me to believe that the OS or mobo doesn't recognise the port as an ethernet port and maybe i need drivers or the drivers aren't being recognised. Can anyone help? I really want to use this OS because it's the staple for computational chemistry and steam has just made its way there, so i figured i might as well start using it as i'm nearing the end of my undergrad and there are now games to be played there.

In case this helps my setup is the following.
gigabyte Z77X-UD3H mobo, i7 3770k OC'd @ 4.7 GHz, gigabyte 7970 Ghz Oc'd to 1.1 Ghz

Answer (score 0):

To find the terminal, just open the dash. (Click the Ubuntu button in the top left corner or press the "Windows"-key on your keyboard.) Then you type in "terminal" and you can open the terminal with a click on the icon.

Now about your network card. It seems like Ubuntu doesn't recognize your network card out of the box. Maybe you just have to install proprietary drivers that Ubuntu can't enable by default for licence reasons. That's fairly easy. [Here is](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers) a nice guide on enabling proprietary drivers for 12.04 and 12.10. (Not that they changed the process in 12.10.)

Should that doesn't work, please tell us, what network card you are using. To do that open up a terminal and type `lspci`. That command will display a list of all your hardware. Copy the list and post it here.

Hope I could help!? :)

Comment: It didn't work, and since i couldn't connect to the internet or save a screenshot onto my windows install i took 2 pictures with my phone of the area corresponding to my ethernet drivers. It's the Atheros communication line. http://imgur.com/DhfA4K1,prFgTeI#0  the other things from the list just lists what i already described above.

Comment: I see... I had the same issue with an atheros card. We'll have to manually download and install the driver. Could you just copy the whole line regarding your network card here please? The chipset name (AR...) is cut off in your photo.

Comment: Just stumbled over the answer that fixed my problem. Might want to try that, if you too have an ar8162 chip. (Might work for other chipsets as well though...) http://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working