# How do I install the correct Ethernet driver?

Tags: drivers, ethernet

So I’m new with Ubuntu, and I'm having huge problems installing the Ethernet driver to get the wired connection to work.

I read that downloading the compatible wireless driver will get it to work, so I did, burned it to a disc, tried to transfer it but don't know the commands to actually install it, nor do I even know if the one I installed is the right one.

I have a Toshiba Satellite L855-S5309, with an `Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)`.

Also, this is the version of compatible I downloaded, `compat-wireless-2012-12-18-pc.tar.bz2` .  How can I solve my issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working

Answer (score 0):

See [How do I get an Atheros AR8162 working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working) for a mini-HOWTO

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/#Additional_patches_to_stable_releases is the source for newer compat-wireless drivers and for different kernels.

You might need to install linux-headers-generic build-essential via apt-get.

Comment: tar -xvf compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar
cd compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p
scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx

Comment: tar -xvf compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar # unpacks the tar-file into the actual directory
cd compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p # change into the new directory
scripts/driver-select alx # selects the appropiate driver alx
make # driver becomes compiled
sudo make install # files will be copied into the kernel directory
sudo modprobe alx # loads the driver as a kernel-module

Comment: Could you roll up your comments into your answer to summarize and clarify your solution?